# Passing a list to a SQL query in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I need to be able to pass a list of undefined size that will contain numbers like so ('1900'),('1920'),... to and OLE DB source in SSIS.

as of right now I am trying a lot of different things that aren't working.

```
declare @fieldLogID nvarchar(256) = ?
declare @accountTypes int = ?

select
      fl.[Version]
      ,fl.ObjectID
      ,[FieldLogID]
      ,Cast(fl.WorkStartDateTime as date) as WorkStartDate
      ,Cast(fl.WorkStartDateTime as time) as WorkStartTime...

...
where fleja.FieldLog_FieldLogID IN (@fieldLogID)
```

The @fieldLogID will contain all the numbers that are passed in. The numbers format does not matter so much, they can be strings, ints, etc. Just as long as we are passing a list.

Any tips on how this is done?

Comment: Are your components on the same SQL Server?  If so, I would probably just use a stored procedure to do the work and not have separate SSIS tasks, ie one 'Execute SQL' task that calls that proc, rather than separate tasks trying to pass data to each other.  See Erland's excellent article on the topic: [http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Comment: That my be a valid way to process this. We have not tried that yet so ill be looking into it. Thank you.

Comment: Similar question from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11568119/181965)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using dynamic sql?  Something like this:

```
declare @fieldLogID nvarchar(256) = ?
declare @accountTypes int = ?
declare @sql nvarchar(1000) = ''

SET @sql = 'select fl.[Version]
           ,fl.ObjectID
           ,[FieldLogID]
           ,Cast(fl.WorkStartDateTime as date) as WorkStartDate
           ,Cast(fl.WorkStartDateTime as time) as WorkStartTime...
           ...
           where fleja.FieldLog_FieldLogID IN (' + @fieldLogID + ')'
EXEC (@sql)
```

The syntax may be a little off and the @sql nvarchar variable type would probably need to be expanded more.   The format for @fieldLogID would need to be something like this though:

```
@fieldLogID = n'''1800'',''1900'',''2000'''
```

Instead of executing the @sql variable, you can always print it to the screen to verify your syntax.  Using this approach I would be a little worried about the @fieldLogID variable and I would like to validate that it is correct and nothing malicious is going in there.

Answer (score 0):

Your "IN" statement will not work unless the @fieldLogID variable is of "TABLE" type and not single value type.

You can either:

Switch the "IN" to a LIKE"  and reverse the two, as such (this is a bit lazy and taxing on resources, at LIKE is sort of expensive):

```
WHERE @fieldLogID LIKE '%' + fleja.FieldLog_FieldLogID + '%'
```

Or (**and my preferred method**) you can declare @fieldLogID as a Single Column Table Variable instead

```
DECLARE @fieldLogID TABLE
AS
(FieldLogID NVARCHAR(256));

INSERT INTO @fieldLogID
(FieldLogID)
SELECT [COLUMN] 
FROM [FieldLogDataSourceTable]
```

Then you'd be able to use your initial WHERE clause, as @fieldLogID is now a table:

```
where fleja.FieldLog_FieldLogID IN (SELECT [FieldLogID] FROM @fieldLogID)
```

You can also try WHERE EXISTS if the IN is too resource expensive, but that gets a bit complicated:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT [FieldLogID] 
              FROM @FieldLogID
              INNER JOIN [fleja]
              ON [fleja].[FieldLog_FieldLogID] = [FieldLogID])
```